# Restrictions on cast unreal

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I know it is possible to cast thing in Unreal using Cast Keyword

```
Cast<Object>(object...)
```

But I was wondering if we could use:

- static_cast
- dynamic_cast
- reinterpret_cast

I created a Interface (pure virtual class), but I saw some problems when doing reinterpret_cast with it.

E.g.

I can have:

```
class IMyInterface {
    void doSomething() = 0;
};

UCLASS()
class MYTEST_API My_Character : public ACharacter, public IMyInterface
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
```

But when I do reinterpret_cast<IMyInterface*> my object is not fully loaded and sometimes the program crashes.

Is there any restrictions doing these common c++ cast in Unreal Engine?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the regular `Cast<>`?

Comment: I'm used to c++ libs I so I tried using the c++ casts (not Unreal ones), but I got some problems and wanted to understand why.

Comment: You may find you are having a hard time in unreal if you don't take the time to adopt their way of doing things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I was wondering if we could use:
>
> - static_cast
> - dynamic_cast
> - reinterpret_cast

Yes, of course you can use these. However, there are some restrictions and do's and don'ts here.

First off, the only casts you'll probably need are the `Cast<T>()` and `StaticCast<T>` which Unreal provides. `Cast<T>()` uses reflection to determine the passed in type and the templated type and try to match them, returning a `nullptr` on failure. Note that, because of the nature of Unreals reflection, `Cast<T>()` only works on types that are `USTRUCT`s or `UCLASS`es. You can look into its inner workings [here in the source](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/5.2/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/Templates/Casts.h#L83).

`StaticCast<T>()` is internally just the `static_cast<T>()` that you are used to. But there are reasons why it exists:

> This exists to avoid a Visual Studio bug where using a cast to forward an rvalue reference array argument to a pointer parameter will cause bad code generation.  Wrapping the cast in a function causes the correct code to be generated.

[Source](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/5.2/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Templates/UnrealTemplate.h#L601)

Using a reinterpret_cast on an `UObject` is most definitely the wrong approach. [Did you know that you can just define `UINTERFACE` implementations and cast typesafe using `Cast<T>()`?](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Interfaces/)
A major issue with that is that holding a reference to an interface does not guarantee the lifetime of the object. So, if you want to keep it alive, you probably want to store the `UObject*` of the interface as a reference, either in a [TStrongObjectPtr](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/TStrongObjectPtr/) or as a `UPROPERTY()` in another `UCLASS()`.